# Evaluating $0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1}+0.3^{2}+\cdots+0.3^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

After the great help I received (on here), I had an easy time working with a similar progression, but this one is giving me trouble. Can anyone sum the following:

$$\begin{align}
&0.3^{-1} \\
&0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0} \\
&0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1} \\
&0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1}+0.3^{2} \\
&\cdots
\end{align}$$ and so on.

I feel very thankful for all the help I've gotten on things thus far; thank you guys, your skills are epic and regarded with great respect, by me!

Comment: Multiply your summation by $1$, but instead of it looking like $1$, use $\frac{0.3}{0.3}$.  Now your series has no negative exponent terms.  The search term to use to continue is "geometric series."

Comment: It is not very clear if you want the sum with infinitely many terms, or the infinitely many sums with $1,2,3,\ldots$ terms, or even the sum of all these sums.

Comment: *"I had an easy time working with a similar progression"* ... Please say what that progression was, how you approached it, and why the given progression seems to have you stumped. This will help people avoid telling you what you already know and focus on making a connection with the problem at hand. (As always, please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3378076/edit) to include clarifications in the body. Comments are easily overlooked.)

Comment: @ajotatxe, if I understand you correctly, I'd like, the 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: Rephrased, ajotatxe is asking if you are looking for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N 0.3^{-2+n} = 0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+\dots+0.3^{n-2}$ or if you are looking for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 0.3^{-2+k}\right) = (0.3^{-1})+(0.3^{-1}+0.3^0)+(0.3^{-1}+0.3^0+0.3^1)+\dots+(0.3^{-1}+\dots+0.3^{n-3}+0.3^{n-2})$

Comment: @Blue, it was of exactly the same form, only like this:

$$\frac{1-0.3^{n+1}}{1-0.3}$$

Comment: And that comment suggests to me that you are looking for the first... or similar... in which case I will reiterate and rephrase the hint in my first comment... factor out a common factor of $0.3^{-1}$ or $0.3^{-2}$ or similar... you get that $(0.3^{-1}+0.3+0.3^1+\dots+0.3^{n-2}) = 0.3^{-1}(0.3^0+0.3^1+0.3^2+\dots+0.3^{n-1})$ and it should now be simply $0.3^{-1}$ times a summation in a form that you are already familiar with

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: That's *very useful* information. So, you know that the sum of the geometric series $1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n$ is $(1-r^{n+1})/(1-r)$. There are a couple of ways to work with this knowledge in the current problem. (1) *Ignore* $0.3^{-1}$, sum the remaining terms w/the formula, then *recall* the $0.3^{-1}$ and add it to that sum. (2, Better) Note that the general geometric series $a+ar+ar^2+\cdots+ar^{n+1}$ has the sum $a(1-r^{n+1})/(1-r)$. (Just factor-out $a$.) Here, $a$ is the first term, and $r$ the common ratio; in the current problem, $a=0.3^{-1}$ and $r=0.3$. (See JMoravitz' way)

Comment: @JMoravitz, it worked perfectly. Great strategy. Can I post the answer or is that bad form here?

Comment: @Blue, the comment was meant for both of you (only one (AT?) allowed). Thanks again.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle Sadly, yes, only one notification per comment, but it is common to reply to multiple people by using a space after the at such as @ Jinny and @ Blue.  Only the one user who immediately follows the at symbol without a space will have the red notification pop up in their display though.  I'm not sure the exact reasoning why it was coded this way.

Comment: By all means, please post the answer that you found.  It is highly encouraged for a number of reasons, not least of which because it shows that the question has been resolved.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle: As for posting the answer yourself: I say "yes". (I often encourage it if one of my comment-hints has helped someone find an answer.) It's a nice way to honor the learning process.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have posted it. Let me know if it's ok as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no different than any other geometric sum.

1) Let $x = 0.3^{-1} + 0.3^0 + ......+0.3^{n}$

$0.3 x  = 0.3^0 + 0.3^1 + ..... +0.3^{n+1}$.

$0.3x(1-0.3) = 1 - 0.3^{n+2}$

$x = \frac {1-0.3^{n+2}}{0.3(1-0.3)} = \frac {0.3^{-1} - 0.3^{n+1}}{1-0.3} = \frac {0.3^{-1} - 0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

2) Let $x = 0.3^{-1} + 0.3^0 + ......+0.3^{n}$

$x -0.3^{-1} = 1 + .... + 0.3^n = \frac {1-0.3^{n+1}}{1-0.3} =\frac {1-0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

$x = \frac {1-0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}+0.3^{-1}$

$= \frac {0.3^{-1}*0.97 + 1-0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

$=\frac {0.3^{-1}*(1-0.3) + 1-0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

$= \frac {0.3^{-1} - 1 + 1-0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}=\frac {0.3^{-1} - 0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

3) Let $x = 0.3^{-1} + 0.3^0 + ......+0.3^{n}$

$x(1-0.3) = (0.3^{-1} + 0.3^0 + ......+0.3^{n})(1-0.3)$

$= (0.3^{-1} + 0.3^0 + ......+0.3^{n})- (0.3^{0} + 0.3^1 + ......+0.3^{n+1})$

$= 0.3^{-1} - 0.3^{n+1}$

So $x = \frac {0.3^{-1} - 0.3^{n+1}}{0.97}$

======

In general $a^{m} + .......  + a^{n}$ can be solved as:

$x =a^{m} + .......  + a^{n}$

$x = a^{m}(1 + ...... + a^{n-m})$

$= a^{m}\frac {1-a^{n-m+1}}{1-a}$

And if $m < 0$ .... well, that makes now difference:

$\begin{align}
x &= a^{-1}+ \cdots + a^{n}\\\\
  &= a^{-1}(1 + \cdots + a^{n-(-1)})=a^{-1}(1 + \cdots + a^{n+1})\\\\
  &= a^{-1}\left(\frac {1-a^{n+2}}{1-a}\right)\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer as a result of great help from JMoravitz and Blue! Thank you guys.

$$f(n)=\left(\frac{1-0.3^{n}}{1-0.3}\right)0.3^{-1}$$

I hope someone finds this of use. I think it's very cool that you can capture something like this in such a small expression.