# Creating A Function For The Following:

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

In trying to manipulate a function arrived at in a prior post, I've arrived at this (as a goal):

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & y \\ \hline
0.3^{-1} & -1 \\
0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0} & 0 \\
0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1}& 1 \\
0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1}+0.3^{2} & 2 \\
0.3^{-1}+0.3^{0}+0.3^{1}+0.3^{2}+0.3^{3} & 3 \\ 
\end{array}$$

But, I'm having issues creating the right function. I'd be very thankful if someone could give me a hand with it!

Comment: @zwim Could you expand the hint ever so slightly? Thank you!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378076/evaluating-0-3-10-300-310-32-cdots0-3n/3378146#3378146 Sorry, I did not understand your question until I saw your other post. So you want to find $y$ given the sum $x$. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes, @zwim, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your other post you were given the formula (where $a=0.3$)

$$x=\dfrac{1-a^{y+2}}{(1-a)a}$$

So isolating $y$ we get $\quad a^{y+2}=1-x(1-a)a\iff y+2=\log_a(1-xa+xa^2)$

The formula you seek is thus $$y=\dfrac{\ln(1-xa+xa^2)}{\ln(a)}-2$$

Comment: Sorry for my comment; I made an error when solving for x. Your work is perfect and awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I think this fulfills what you are asking for.
$$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}$$
\begin{equation}y={\argmax_{\sum_{i=-1}^{a}{0.3^i}\le x
}}a
\end{equation}

Achieving a smooth function <s>may not be</s> is possible (look at zwim's answer).

Comment: This fulfills the vague question without mindreading. zwim's answer probably fulfills the asker's intent, and is not a step function.

Comment: Not what I intended, but still a really clever thought!